# How does Apache manages TCP connections between user and Jonas ?

Tags: apache, tcp, jonas

I have a Java Application deployed on a Jonas behind a Apache server. The java application is used to download files.
To download a file, a user sends a get. So there are two TCP connections : one from the user to Apache, one from Apache to Jonas.

My problem is : Jonas sends the file ways faster than Apache sends to the user. When Jonas has sent all the file, it closes its half part of the connection trhough a FIN,ACK. Apache answers with a RST, and closes the connection with the user trhough FIN,ACK, even if the user has not received all data.

Below a network capture of the problem

Connections are User:54234 ---- 8089 Apache 55903 ---- 9019 Jonas

```
Time            Source                Src. Port Destination           Dest. Port Protocol Length Info                                                              
14:16:43.898743 10.99.111.149         9019      10.99.111.149         55903      TCP      16452  9019 > 55903 [ACK] Seq=101869713 Ack=332 Win=34304 Len=16396[Packet size limited during capture] 0.000015    0.000015000
14:16:43.898978 10.99.111.149         55903     10.99.111.149         9019       TCP      56     55903 > 9019 [ACK] Seq=332 Ack=101886109 Win=24064 Len=0            
14:16:43.898992 10.99.111.149         9019      10.99.111.149         55903      TCP      12891  9019 > 55903 [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=101886109 Ack=332 Win=34304 Len=12835 
14:16:43.899004 10.99.111.149         55903     10.99.111.149         9019       TCP      56     55903 > 9019 [ACK] Seq=332 Ack=101898945 Win=11264 Len=0            
14:16:43.899188 10.99.111.149         55903     10.99.111.149         9019       TCP      56     55903 > 9019 [RST, ACK] Seq=332 Ack=101898945 Win=639488 Len=0      
14:16:43.899399 10.99.111.149         8089      10.99.111.157         54234      TCP      56     8089 > 54234 [FIN, ACK] Seq=4159541 Ack=258 Win=15872 Len=0     
14:16:43.900091 10.99.111.157         54234     10.99.111.149         8089       TCP      62     54234 > 8089 [ACK] Seq=258 Ack=4159542 Win=65535 Len=0          
14:16:44.013833 10.99.111.157         54234     10.99.111.149         8089       TCP      62     54234 > 8089 [FIN, ACK] Seq=258 Ack=4159542 Win=65535 Len=0     
14:16:44.013880 10.99.111.149         8089      10.99.111.157         54234      TCP      56     8089 > 54234 [ACK] Seq=4159542 Ack=259 Win=15872 Len=0
```

My questions are :

- is this the normal behaviour from Apache ? Can Apache buffer all data before sending it to the user ?
- Is it configurable through mod_jk or in Apache configuration ?
- RST being sent when problems occurs on TCP connections, is there a log file dedicated to these problems ?

Comment: If Apache answers with an RST, somebody is doing something wrong, probably closing the socket before reading all the pending incoming data.

Comment: @EJP, do you mean the problem is on Apache ?